# How to add an arrow reprents inscrease

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I'm trying to add an arrow that represents the increse of some values (so, not fix). But I don't know how to make it. Apparently Highcharts doesn't have any function to make it simple...

http://jsfiddle.net/bm68vj4r/1/

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Marker has a 'symbol' attribute which allows you to set custom/default marker symbols. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chart.renderer.path()` to generate your own path, here is a simple snippet to achieve that: http://jsfiddle.net/bm68vj4r/2/

```
function drawIncrease() {
  var chart = this,
    r = chart.renderer,
    styles = {
      'stroke-width': 2,
      'stroke': 'black',
      'zIndex': 5
    };

  chart.increaseLine = r.path().attr(styles).add();

  redrawIncrease.call(this);
}

function redrawIncrease() {

  var chart = this,
    r = chart.renderer,
    left = chart.plotLeft,
    top = chart.plotTop,
    series_0 = chart.series[0],
    series_2 = chart.series[2],
    x_1 = series_0.points[0].plotX + left + series_0.pointXOffset,
    x_2 = series_2.points[1].plotX + left + series_2.pointXOffset,
    y_1 = series_0.points[0].plotY + top,
    y_2 = series_2.points[1].plotY + top,
    path = ['M', x_1, y_1, 'L', x_2, y_2];


  if (chart.increaseLine) {
    chart.increaseLine.attr({
      d: path
    })
  }
}
```

You can modify `path` to add arrow head. `plotLeft` and `plotTop` are offsets for plotting area. `pointXOffset` is offset for a series (column) to the centre of the category.

Comment: Great ! Thanks. But I don't get how to add arrow head ?

Comment: For example like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bm68vj4r/3/ - I mean calculate arrowhead and update path accordingly. Probably [this should help](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68033/calculating-edge-coordinates-of-arrowhead-pretty-basic-trigonometry).

Comment: @PawełFus You, sir, are great.